# PHP - Check if given Date fits a given interval

Tags: php, date, datetime

If I have a `DateTime` interval, such as:

```
$slot_interval = DateInterval::createFromDatestring('30 minutes');
```

And another `DateTime` object with any date, how can I check that the object fits the interval? So if the interval is 30 min, then dates such as `2016-10-04 12:00:00` and `2016-10-04 14:30:00` would be valid, while `2016-10-04 12:05:10` is not valid anymore?

I could not find many resources for this, except some solutions for MySQL and/or converting dates to unix timestamps, doing division in seconds and checking remainder. Was wondering if there is a nicer and better solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $minutes = date('i',strtotime($inputDate);
 $seconds = date('s',strtotime($inputDate);
 if((($minutes == '00') || ($minutes == '30')) && ($seconds == '00')){
     // do stuff
 }
```

Comment: Yes I could do check like this, but the `$slot_interval` might be anything like `1 hour`, `2 hours`, `15 minutes`, `30 seconds` etc., so I was wondering if there is a solution to use the actual `DateInterval` object for the calculation

Comment: @Giedrius  so `$slot_interval` in not a date?  Could you post your full code.  Not quite sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: `$slot_interval` is a `DateInterval` object as per above. What I am trying to achieve is to validate a `DateTime` object (not `$slot_interval`) to check if it matches the interval as defined by `$slot_interval`

Comment: @Giedrius I edited code to account for seconds as well.  This will make it so only date times that are exactly '00' or '30' minutes get flagged.  If that is not the answer you are looking for, could you tell me the actual application and some more example code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The answer is correct for this particular case, so I have marked it as so. However, for future reference I was looking if there was a function that would make use of the `DateInterval` object and validate a `DateTime` object without the use of pre-defined values (like `30` minutes and `00` seconds). For example, if `DateInterval` is `15 minutes 15 seconds` it would be much harder to validate using your method.